# YouTube API Search: list - order by viewCount. How to query all videos?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**Goal: Get all (non-live) videos uploaded on October 2020 order by viewCount**

My first try was like this:

```
request = youtube.search().list(
    part="snippet",
    order="viewCount",
    publishedAfter="2020-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    publishedBefore="2020-10-31T23:59:59Z",
    type="video",
    maxResults=50
)
```

It returns me `YpUR1rHXbqs` video which is live (and still running). IMHO it doesn't fit `publishedBefore="2020-10-31T23:59:59Z"` since it still running, but never mind.

I try to filter out live videos with:

```
response = request.execute()
for item in response["items"]:
  if item["snippet"]["liveBroadcastContent"] != 'live':
```

It returns `o6zDG9jYpC0` with 7 624 725 views today and `'liveBroadcastContent'='none'` Seems too little to me.

So I try add `q="a"` to check if `o6zDG9jYpC0` is the most viewed one:

```
request = youtube.search().list(
    q='a',
    part="snippet",
    order="viewCount",
    publishedAfter="2020-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    publishedBefore="2020-10-31T23:59:59Z",
    type="video",
    maxResults=50
)
```

Returns `uy30PB5BpV0` with 192 861 990 views :-( and `'liveBroadcastContent'='none'`

I try to experiment with `q=""`, `q="*"`, `q="%2A"`, `q="+"`, `q=" "`, `q=None` ... , but no luck.

Adding `eventType="completed"` seems to work well with missing/not set `q` but it omits `'liveBroadcastContent'='none'` videos.

How can I query all videos please?

Side note: I'm aware of Video: list (most popular videos) chart='mostPopular' but it doesn't support `publishedAfter/Before` which is required